# How can I "link" two objects (like a keyword and its synonyms) in a php function?

Tags: php, html, function

I'm creating a form using php, html, css, and javascript.

On this form, the person needs to choose a few keywords and its synonyms.

It looks like this:

```
     <form action="create.php" class="col-md-10 offset-md-1" method="post"> 
    <div class="form-group" id="duplicateKeyWordAndSynonym">
    <label for="keyWord">Type a keyword.</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" id="terms" name="terms[]"></textarea> <br/>
    <label for="synonym">Type the synonyms of your keyword.</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" id="synonym" name="synonym[]"></textarea> <br/>
    </div>        
    <button class="glass-button" type="button" id="add">click here to add more keywords and 
    synonyms.</button>
    </form>
    <script>
    //https://api.jquery.com/click/
    $("#add").click(function () {
    //https://api.jquery.com/append/
    $("#duplicateKeyWordAndSynonym").append('here is the code to duplicate the keywords and 
    synonyms part.');
                });
   </script>
```

Now, I have to connect my keywords to my synonyms on "create.php" so I can send this to the back-end.

I have tried a few things, but nothing seems to work.

This was my first try:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($terms); $i++) {
          echo "TERM".$terms[$i];
          echo "\nSynonym ".$synonym[$i];
          $list[$terms[$i]] = $synonym[$i];
          }
```

Last thing I tried was this:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($terms); $i++) {
        echo "TERM".$terms[$i];
        echo "\nSYNONYMS ".$synonims[$i];
        $list->add("keyword" => $terms[$i],
                    "synonym" =>  $synonims[$i]);
    }
```

It didn't work. What should I do?

======================================
Edit: Thanks for your comments, guys! This is how I solved the problem:

```
    class Keyword{
    public $keyword;
    public $synonyms;
    public function setKeyword($keyword){
        $this->keyword = $keyword;
    }
    public function getKeyword(){
        return $this->keyword;
    }
    public function setSynonyms($synonyms){
        $this->synonyms = $synonyms;
    }
    public function getSynonyms(){
        return $this->synonyms;
    }
}

$terms = $_POST['terms'];
$synonym = $_POST['synonym'];
$arrayKeywords = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < count($terms); $i++) {
            $keyword = new Keyword(); 
            $keyword->setKeyword($terms[$i]); 
            $keyword->setSynonyms($synonym[$i]);
            $arrayKeywords[] = $keyword; 
}
```

Comment: Use an associative array where the keys are the keywords and values are arrays of synonyms.

Comment: _It didn't work_  What does that mean?

Comment: You're not using `$_POST` vars and in one example you have `$synonym` and the next `$synonims`.

Answer (score 0):

You can submit the form in two ways:

1- in javascript, by putting in the script ( document.getElementById("myForm").submit(); ) where myForm is the id form .

2- in php, at the button level put type="submit" instead of "button".

You can retrieve the data in the page "create.php" by $_POST['terms'] and $_POST['synonym']